# How to add radio button to a grid in GWT?

Tags: gwt, radio-button, gxt

I have a Grid in my panel.
I want to add Radio on the grid as a Column, but am not quite sure how to do it.
Please tell me how can I have a Radio button column config.

I tried to search in google, but found no solution over it.
Any help is appreciated
:)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976379/checkboxes-to-select-an-entry-in-a-grid-gwt

Answer (score 0):

You can build a custom cell that renders as

```
<input type="radio" name="group" value="" />
```

This is a tutorial on building custom cells:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomCells